# SAS macro works with one variable but not another. Cluster 2-ols macro Error: (execution) invalid argument

Tags: sas, sas-iml

Here is my macro:

```
%MACRO clus2OLS(yvar, xvars, cluster1, cluster2, dset=);
    /* do interesection cluster*/
    proc surveyreg data=&dset; cluster &cluster1 &cluster2; model &yvar= &xvars /  covb; ods output CovB = CovI; quit;
    /* Do first cluster */
    proc surveyreg data=&dset; cluster &cluster1; model &yvar= &xvars /  covb; ods output CovB = Cov1; quit;
    /* Do second cluster */
    proc surveyreg data=&dset; cluster &cluster2; model &yvar= &xvars /  covb; ods output CovB = Cov2 ParameterEstimates = params;  quit;

    /*  Now get the covariances numbers created above. Calc coefs, SEs, t-stats, p-vals using COV = COV1 + COV2 - COVI*/
    proc iml; reset noprint; use params;
        read all var{Parameter} into varnames;
        read all var _all_ into b;
        use Cov1; read all var _num_ into x1;
        use Cov2; read all var _num_ into x2;
        use CovI; read all var _num_ into x3;

        cov = x1 + x2 - x3; /* Calculate covariance matrix */
        dfe = b[1,3]; stdb = sqrt(vecdiag(cov)); beta = b[,1]; t = beta/stdb; prob = 1-probf(t#t,1,dfe); /* Calc stats */

        print,"Parameter estimates",,varnames beta[format=8.4] stdb[format=8.4] t[format=8.4] prob[format=8.4];

          conc =    beta || stdb || t || prob;
          cname = {"estimates" "stderror" "tstat" "pvalue"};
          create clus2dstats from conc [ colname=cname ];
          append from conc;

          conc =   varnames;
          cname = {"varnames"};
          create names from conc [ colname=cname ];
          append from conc;
    quit;

    data clus2dstats; merge names clus2dstats; run;
%MEND clus2OLS;
```

Here is my macro call:

```
*call cluster 2-ols macro for first chgroa1 model;
%clus2OLs(yvar=Chgroa3, xvars=vb_nvb roa chgroa GrAS, cluster1=gvkey, cluster2=fyear, dset=Reg_ROA);
*set up macro for second chgroa1 model;
%clus2OLS(yvar=Chgroa3, xvars=SERIAL roa chgroa GrAS, cluster1=gvkey, cluster2=fyear, dset=Reg_ROA);
*set up macro for third chgroa1 model;
%clus2OLS(yvar=Chgroa3, xvars=recyc_V roa chgroa GrAS, cluster1=gvkey, cluster2=fyear, dset=Reg_ROA);
*set up macro for fourth chgroa1 model;
```

I use similar code with the only difference being the `yvar=Chgroa3`. When I use `yvar=Chgroa1` it works. Otherwise I get error message

```
NOTE: IML Ready
ERROR: (execution) Invalid argument to function.

 operation : SQRT at line 4121 column 1
 operands  : _TEM1001

_TEM1001      5 rows      1 col     (numeric)

 0.0002809
 0.0005076
 0.0112643
  -0.00117
 0.0018209

 statement : ASSIGN at line 4121 column 1
ERROR: (execution) Matrix has not been set to a value.

 operation : / at line 4121 column 1
 operands  : beta, stdb

beta      5 rows      1 col     (numeric)

 -0.026229
 -0.018565
 -0.484585
 -0.086641
 -0.052028

stdb      0 row       0 col     (type ?, size 0)


 statement : ASSIGN at line 4121 column 1
ERROR: (execution) Matrix has not been set to a value.
```

Comment: Just guessing from the error msg, but are you possibly trying to take the square root of a negative number?

Comment: Quentin, that is a good guess, but my other variable works (Chgroa1) and it has positive and negative numbers as well.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-IML-Software-and-Matrix/Macro-OLS-with-two-way-cluster/m-p/486782#M4305 As Joe says, there is no reason to expect that the linear combination of covariance matrices should be positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin notes in the comments, you're trying to take the square root of a negative number.  See the fourth line of the temporary matrix printed to the log; it's negative.  (Note that the variable itself is fine to be negative, but the covariance cannot be.)

See the following example code with the identical error:

```
13   proc iml;
NOTE: IML Ready
14     x = {1 2 -3};
15     y = sqrt(x);
ERROR: (execution) Invalid argument to function.

 operation : SQRT at line 15 column 11
 operands  : x

x      1 row       3 cols    (numeric)

         1         2        -3

 statement : ASSIGN at line 15 column 3
16   quit;
```

I'm not familiar with that particular equation, but you should verify that it's logically possible for `Cov1+Cov2-CovI` to be negative; it seems like it shouldn't be, to me.

Comment: okay that's a good point, but how can I fix this? I searched my dataset for the numbers shown in my error message and could not find them. So I assume they are calculated numbers, and those calculated numbers are what is throwing things off.  This code works for 3 other variables with similar numbers - so it works, just not for this one variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I said - verify if it’s possible for the intersection term to be what it is. This is either a data problem or an equation problem.